# create a pandas dataframe column on the basis of another column value

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a column website in pandas dataframe , which has  values like expedia,MMT,Booking.com etc

I want to add two column in dataframe.

1) My_Site which should have site column values like 'Expedia' and 'MMT'
2)another column Cmp_site which has all values of site column except values of newly built My_site column.

For example

webSite column has values expedia,MMT,Booking.com

now Mysite column should have expedia,MMT
and  Cmp_site should have Booking.com

please help !

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: df['My_Site'] = pd.np.where(df['SITE']='expedia')

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a dataframe like this:

```
      My_Site
0     Expedia
1  MakeMyTrip
2     Booking
```

You now want other sites next to each site for comparison purposes. For this, I would use `itertools` to generate the combinations. I will restrict the combinations to 2 because that is what we want.

```
import itertools

newList = []

for subset in itertools.combinations(siteList, 2):
    newList.append(subset)

newList = [list(row) for row in newList]
```

At this point, your newList looks like:

```
[['Expedia', 'MakeMyTrip'], ['Expedia', 'Booking'], ['MakeMyTrip', 'Booking']]
```

Now get them to a `pandas` dataframe by assigning them to a `list`, and using the `list` as `dataframe` columns:

```
mySite = []
cmpSite = []

for i in range(len(level1)):
    mySite.append(newList[i][0])
    cmpSite.append(newList[i][1])

newDf = pd.DataFrame()
newDf['My_Site'] = mySite
newDf['Cmp_Site'] = cmpSite
```

Final output:

```
Out[90]: 
      My_Site    Cmp_Site
0     Expedia  MakeMyTrip
1     Expedia     Booking
2  MakeMyTrip     Booking
```

You now have combinations for each site to compare with other sites.